# differential equation of concentric circle and its rotate direction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I define the direction of the normal form of concentric circle? $x(t)=C_1\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
       \cos\beta t\\
      -\sin\beta t\\
    \end{array}
  \right)
+C_2\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
       \sin\beta t\\
      \cos\beta t\\
    \end{array}
  \right)$

I have no idea how to define the circle direction of concentric circle

Comment: What do you mean by "the direction"?

Comment: @WalterJ The direction of rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully sure, but maybe this helps. 
You have $x(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\beta t) & \sin(\beta t)\\ -\sin(\beta t) & \cos(\beta t) \end{pmatrix} x_0$, which is expressing a clockwise rotation for the usual $(\beta, t)$ (changed the $C$'s to $x_0$). Then by differentiation find that $\dot{x}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} -\sin(\beta t) & \cos(\beta t)\\ -\cos(\beta t) & -\sin(\beta t) \end{pmatrix} \beta x_0$ such that for example when given $x_0=(1,0)$ the corresponding derivative (direction) becomes $\dot{x}(t)|_{t=0}=(0,-\beta)$. Which, if you draw a radius $1$ circle with $x_0$ on it, is what you should expect.

Comment: you mean $\dot{x}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} -\sin(\beta t) & \cos(\beta t)\\ -\cos(\beta t) & -\sin(\beta t) \end{pmatrix} \beta x_0$ ?

Comment: Yes, typo. fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much WalterJ.  It helped to understand.

Comment: If stuck with these kind of questions, drawing might do wonders!